# How to add a new top-level entity (to rest web service endpoint) using acumatica screenID?

Tags: acumatica

Acumatica cloud ERP has a screen that displays failed push notifications (screenID = SM502000). I have created a new Web Services Endpoint, and added a new top-level entity from that screenID. However, no matter what fields I try to add, I get a variation on this error:

`Optimization cannot be performed.The following fields cause the error:\r\nSelected: View FailedToSend has BQL delegate\r\n`

Edit. I was able to create a REST end-point to fetch the results using a generic inquiry. Here is the JSON returned:

```
{
    "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "note": null,
    "Result": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "note": null,
            "Date": {
                "value": 637167021636873690
            },
            "DateTimeStamp": {
                "value": "2020-02-07T19:56:03.687369+00:00"
            },
            "DestinationNamePushNotifications_hookId": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "DestinationNamePushNotifications_hookId_description": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "Error": {
                "value": "Send to target test failed. Message: WebHook returns not success code: NotFound; Message: Tunnel webhook.local not found"
            },
            "NotificationBody": {
                "value": "..."
            },
            "PushNotifications_selected": {},
            "Selected": {
                "value": false
            },
            "SourceName": {
                "value": "SO-SalesOrder"
            },
            "TransactionId": {
                "value": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "files": []
        },
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "rowNumber": 2,
            "note": null,
            "Date": {
                "value": 637167021636873690
            },
            "DateTimeStamp": {
                "value": "2020-02-07T19:56:03.687369+00:00"
            },
            "DestinationNamePushNotifications_hookId": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "DestinationNamePushNotifications_hookId_description": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "Error": {
                "value": "Send to target test failed. Message: WebHook returns not success code: NotFound; Message: Tunnel webhook.local not found"
            },
            "NotificationBody": {
                "value": "..."
            },
            "PushNotifications_selected": {},
            "Selected": {
                "value": false
            },
            "SourceName": {
                "value": "SO-SalesOrder"
            },
            "TransactionId": {
                "value": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "files": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a good tutorial for using GI to access data via API:

https://www.acumatica.com/blog/contract-based-apis-in-generic-inquiries/

Comment: Try to use PUT request and pass the value for some column

Comment: I tried PUT but as Hugues suggested, I am only getting one record back.

Comment: As a workaround you can create a separate page or GI returning the records from the database and send requests to the GI.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I got it to work and I'm now able to fetch all records using PUT rest call. One more quick question: how do I filter these records? I tried `$filter = Date ge xxxxxx` but get an error: `The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Comment: the $filter is correct, the error that you got means that the Date fields is not present in the endpoint fields definition or is not on the highest level

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Since this is a generic inquiry, the 'list' of results is actually an array of items in the Result field (top level). Basically, I get one record back that has Result field that actually contains all the records I need. I tried doing something like `$filter = Result.Date ge 'xxx'` but that also breaks: `The child type 'Result.Date' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types` I'm assuming filtering by values of 'child' fields is not allowed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please add the resulting JSON to the question?

Comment: Updated the question and added the JSON response - let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: You need to have a header filtration and pass the value you want in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try retrieving the records one by one with a REST filter in the URL. The issue is that the target graph you added has a data view (FailedToSend) which uses a data view delegate.

Because data view delegates can be slower than no delegates the API refuses to return more than one record as an optimization.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a way to create a 'basic inquiry' and use that to fetch multiple records at a time? I need to be able to retrieve multiple records.